# np.genfromtxt returns string with 'b'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, genfromtxt

I am learning about different functions of NUmpy, And I have a dummy dataset [here](http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-18-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-sales/) named as 100-Sales-Records.

Now I want to read it using `np.genfromtxt`. My code to read it is

```
df3 = np.genfromtxt('100 Sales Records.csv', delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=None)
```

Because it is a 'csv' file and have strings as well as float.
Now the Output of

`pd.DataFramge(df3).head()`
is
[image]

WHich you can see that all strings have `b` in front of them. WHat is this `b` and how to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that `b` before strings means that it is a byte object normally returned with `utf-8` encoding. It is a bytes object.

To remove it, there is a parameter in `genfromtxt` that is `encoding`, set it to `utf-8`

i.e

```py
df3 = np.genfromtxt('100 Sales Records.csv', delimiter=',',names=True, dtype=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

This will give you the desired results.

Comment: This does not work for me

Comment: @cssstudent try `latin1` or `latin-1` encoding

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I found another way out